# How to reset the border thickness of a radio button in windows phone app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, radio-button

The xaml code for the radio button is,

```
<RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton1" BorderBrush="#b2b2b2" IsChecked="true" Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="0.5" Background="White" Content="Taxable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="78" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Width="164"/>
```

But there is no change in the border thickness, what ever the value i give.
How can this problem be solved, i just want to change the borderthickness of the radio button(FYI - Borderbrush works fine).

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to retemplate the `RadioButton` if you want to change that.

The default template has the background circle defined like this:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="CheckBackground" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25.5" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
         Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
         StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource PhoneStrokeThickness}" 
         VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="25.5"/>
```

Notice that the `StrokeThickness` property is set to a `ThemeResource`, not to a `TemplateBinding` the way `Stroke` is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            <Border BorderBrush="#b2b2b2" BorderThickness="10.0" Width="164">
                <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton1"  IsChecked="true" Foreground="Black" Content="Taxable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="78" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="164"/>
            </Border>
```